# sequential number as long as they are in the same category, but if the category changes, the numbers start over for each category

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns in my Sheet, one for the serial numbers and the other for the category.

I want the numbers to be sequential as long as they are in the same category, but if the category changes, I want the numbers to start over for each category.

And I want all of this to be in Arrayformula.

Note: I was able to do the first part, but I could not make it into Arrayformula.

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. Please checkout [tour] and the tag wikis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the category names are in column `B2:B`, put this formula in row `2` of a free column:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / countifs( B2:B, B2:B, row(B2:B), "<=" & row(B2:B) ) ^ -1 ) )`